# Confidence interval calculation in R. Error not falling outside the interval the expected proprtion of times

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have coded a really simple sampling simulation below. In words the situation is as follows. We have an actual value (which I have assumed to be equal to 0) that we want measure. The variable is sampled with added (Gaussian) noise a random number of times in any experiment. The code just simulates a several such experiments

```
N_EXPERIMENTS  <- 3000
nSamplesInExperiment <- round(runif(N_EXPERIMENTS, 50,500))

experiments <- sapply(nSamplesInExperiment , function(nSamples){

  # Sample the value with some added (Gaussian) noise
  samples  <- rnorm(nSamples, sd=300) 
  mu       <- mean(samples) # Estimate the value

  return(list(
    n          = nSamples,
    estimate   = mu,
    error      = qnorm(0.975)*sd(samples)/sqrt(nSamples)
  ))

})

df <- as.data.frame(t(experiments))

# Cast from list to numeric
for(c in rownames(experiments)){ 
  df[[c]] <- as.numeric(df[[c]])
}
```

Example output:

```
> head(df)
    n   estimate    error
1 280 -21.837431 29.44762
2 456 -11.174191 23.31647
3 393   2.542489 26.49285
```

Note that the estimate is the same as the difference from the actual value (actual is zero). Now I would expect to confidence interval to contain the actual value ~.975 of experiments.

```
sum(df$error > abs(df$estimate))/nrow(df)
```

However this value appears to always be less than .975. How am I misinterpreting/miscalculating the confidence interval?

Comment: You're trying to do too much at once. (1) By varying $n$, you are introducing an unnecessary complication.  Study the situation for a fixed $n$. (2) By using an approximate CI, rather than an exact one, you are confounding the intended coverage with the closeness of approximation. Use a confidence interval method that is known to be exact. (3) Use smaller $n$ so that you can run a much larger `N_EXPERIMENTS` to eliminate concerns about simulation variability.

Comment: Thanks, I have just re run the simulation with fixed `n` (much smaller) a few times and the proportion is still smaller. Given that my signal noise is Gaussian I would have thought that `qnorm(.975)*sd(samples)/sqrt(nSamples)` would be the appropriate estimate? What would you recommend?

Comment: Our site has many related answers at http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=confidence+interval+simulation+answers%3A1.  I recommend using an exact confidence interval. You appear to have rediscovered Student's (1908) finding that this formula gives intervals that are too short on average. In light of that finding, `R` will calculate the Student t distribution for you.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your help. A little more study required on my part I think.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on Student t testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution#Confidence_intervals) might be a good place to start.